# calling web service using jquery

Tags: web-services, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm trying to call a local webservice/webApi using jquery, but I have been stuck for days. could somebody help me please.

So my webservice is sitting on localhost port 4011 i.e. localhost:4011/api/poi/

And my javascript is sitting on local host port localhost:4213/ and here is how I call it:

```
    $.get('http://localhost:4011/api/values', function (data) {
        alert(data);
    });
```

When I enter the url into the browser directly, it returned the result. But when I'm calling it using the jquery. I have no response (by looking from the developer tools).

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Please help.

I'm using webApi mvc .net4 if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). Because the API is on a different port to where you're serving the web page the browser will not allow you to make the request.

You can use jsonp to get around this, or by using cross origin policy on your web service.

Answer (score 1):

Use this if you are using a CrossDomain as CrossDomain doesn't work in jQuery!

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'ajax/test.html',
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function(data) {
        alert(data);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you might be restricted by the cross origin policy [**CORS**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Configure your web service to accept the requests made from across the domain. You can add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` headers like

```
responseMessage.Headers.Add("Access-Control-Allow-Origin","*");
```